# Error with openssl when trying to install pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, openssl

I have created an environment and have python and all other packages installed in it. Openssl is also available when I check using conda list. But unfortunately, I realized pytorch is missing when I check the list of installed packages. When I try to download the pytorch I get the following error.

CondaSSLError: Encountered an SSL error. Most likely a certificate verification issue.
Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is related to ssl updates

run the below code in terminal and try again;

> conda update --all --no-deps certifi

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error trying to download pytorch from the website. My problem apparently was that in my pip.conf file, I had precised a url under the *global* settings to download packages from private sources, possibly preventing the access to other urls (not sure of the mechanics at play here). When removing it, everything worked smoothly.